# Find one eigenvector

Tags: performance, numpy, scipy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

Suppose I have a really large (symmetric) matrix M of size N by N and I just want to extract one eigenvector corresponding to one eigenvalue. Is there a way to do this without finding all the eigenvectors. One way I thought of doing this is to first find the eigenvalues (which is fast) and then solve for one eigenvector.

```
E = np.linalg.eigvalsh(M)
e = E[N/2]
v = np.linalg.solve(E-np.diag([e]*N), 0)
```

But of course you can guess that the solution of this is just v=0. I could do an SVD decomposition of M-eI but I this seems to slower than just computing all the eigenvectors of M.

Comment: IIRC, `shift-qr` is the algorithm that can do this. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html. The `sigma` argument might be of particular interest. Note that this is the sparse linalg version. I am not sure if a `shift-qr` algorithm is also implemented in the regular linalg module.

Comment: Sigma was exactly the parameter I was looking for. Thanks @cel!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
```

Take a look at the docstring - there is a parameter `k` that sets how many eigenvalues and vectors are to be calculated. If I recall correctly, this is done by an iterative scheme from ARPACK. So make sure you set `tol` to an appropriate value for your application.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think this answers the question of how to find an eigenvector from the top (bottom?) of the spectrum. I was interested in how to find an eigenvector corresponding to any eigenvalue.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point, I misunderstood. The typical algorithm for that is the inverse power method. Not to be applied naively, because your matrix is big. But googling a little shows that the first comment on your original post is probably the way to go.

Comment: Cool. My bad since my question was phrased a bit inexactly. I appreciate the help.